# Комбобокс с чекбоксами

Tags: qt, gui, qt4

Необходимо сделать комбобокс с чекбоксами с возможностью множественного выбора. Выбор пункта должен происходить не только по нажатию на непосредственно чекбокс, но и на текст рядом с ним. Проще говоря, аналогично тегу "for" у label для чекбоксов, например, в html. 
Т.е. список не должен закрываться при нажатии на какой-либо пункт из него.

Сейчас у меня комбобокс с чекбоксами реализован следующим образом:

```
  QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);
  QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(COUNT_ROWS, 1);
  for (int i = 0, sz = COUNT_ROWS; i < sz; ++i)
  {
    QStandardItem* newitem = new QStandardItem;
    newitem->setData("sometitle", Qt::EditRole);
    newitem->setData(NUMBER, Qt::UserRole);
    newitem->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    newitem->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
    model->setItem(i,0,newitem);     
  }
  editor->setModel(model);
```

Множественный выбор присутствует, чекбоксы отображаются, текст тоже. 
Проблема - отловить момент нажатия на текст, чтобы установить значение соответствующего чекбокса.

Также в `GNOME` не показываются чекбоксы.

Comment: Смотрите делегаты

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за подсказку, не могли бы Вы чуть подробнее рассказать, как именно в данной ситуации нужно использовать делегатов?

Comment: Делегат -- виджет, который отрисовывается в ячейке, соответственно, при клике на ячейку вы тыкаете на делегат, а дальше делаете с этим что хотите

Answer (score 1):

> Как получить сигнал нажатия на пункт комбобокса (весь или текст)?

Не очень понятен вопрос, а точнее, что именно Вы ожидаете. Нажатие кнопки мыши в раскрывающемся списке, что по самому квадратику чекбокса, что по тексту, приведёт к закрытию этого самого списка и установке выбранного элемента текущим. Тогда просто привязывайтесь к соответствующему сигналу списка и меняйте в модели состояние чекбокса:

```
void MyClass::onCurrentIndexChanged(int row) {
    const QModelIndex index = model->index(row,0);

    const Qt::CheckState check_state
        = static_cast<Qt::CheckState>(index
            .data(Qt::CheckStateRole).toInt());

    model->setData(index
        , (check_state == Qt::Checked)
            ? Qt::Unchecked : Qt::Checked
        , Qt::CheckStateRole);
}
```

> Если же я помещаю чекбокс в первую колонку, текст - во вторую,
>   чекбоксы есть, но текст рядом с ними не отображается

`QComboBox` использует одноколоночную модель, вызывая `QListView` для демонстрации списка элементов.

> Также в GNOME не показываются чекбоксы.

Используйте свой `QListView`:

```
QListView *view = new QListView(this);
view->setModel(model);

QComboBox *cbox = new QComboBox(this);
cbox->setModel(model);
cbox->setView(view);
```

Comment: наличие чекбоксов подразумевает возможность множественного выбора, т.е. список не должен закрываться при нажатии на какой-либо пункт из него. Сейчас добавлю в вопрос уточнение. Т.е. сигнал выбора текущего пункта не подойдет. Задача стоит выбирать пункты не только нажатием на чекбоксы, но и на текст рядом с этими чекбоксами, по аналогии с тегом "for" у label в html для чекбоксов, например.